Combinations of two table
I would like to find all the possible combinations between TSet1 and TSet2 to create a table of 18 rows.
TSet1=Select[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], Total@# == 3 &]
TSet2=Select[Tuples[Range[0, 1], 3], Total@# == 2 &]

{{0,1,2},{0,2,1},{1,0,2},{1,1,1},{1,2,0},{2,0,1},{2,1,0}}
{{0,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0}}

In the first list, TSet1=Select[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], Total@# == 3 &]. I have an unwanted set {1,1,1}. How can I modify the code?
I want to get these results:  {{0,1,2},{0,2,1},{1,0,2},{1,2,0},{2,0,1},{2,1,0}}
To obtain a table that is a combination of the two tables and contains 18 rows (6 times 3 equals 18)
Then, put the cells of each row in the function (fx) to get the result in a new column
fx = x1 x2 x3 + x1 x4 x5 + x1 x2 x5 x6 + x1 x3 x4 x6;
If[fx > 0, 1, 0]

The result of the equation is conditional. If the function (fx) is greater than or equal to one, we substitute (1). On the other hand, we substitute (0).
The output is in the form

My attempt
fx = Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] + 
   Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 5] + 
   Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 5] Subscript[x, 6] + 
   Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 6];
(data = Catenate /@ 
    Tuples[{TSet1, TSet2}]) // MatrixForm; LLR1 = {Block[{Subscript}, 
   Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 6}];
   fx]};
(table = Prepend[
    Transpose@Join[{Range@Length@data}, Transpose@data, LLR1], 
    Flatten[{"order", Subscript["x", #] & /@ Range[6], "fx"}]]) // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &


In the first list, TSet1=Select[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], Total@# == 3 &]. I have an unwanted set {1,1,1}. How can I modify the code?
I want to get these results:  {{0,1,2},{0,2,1},{1,0,2},{1,2,0},{2,0,1},{2,1,0}}
How to convert function(fx) values ​​to {0,1} by  If[fx > 0, 1, 0]
Thanks for the help

Well, you want to first generate Tuples: Catenate /@ Tuples[{TSet1, TSet2}]. How to then create new column with conditions was already answered in your previous question.

@Domen In the first list, TSet1=Select[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], Total@# == 3 &]. I have an unwanted set {1,1,1}. How can I modify the code?
I want to get these results:  {{0,1,2},{0,2,1},{1,0,2},{1,2,0},{2,0,1},{2,1,0}}

Well, if you don't want it, just change the condition: TSet1 = Select[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], Total@# == 3 && # != {1, 1, 1} &]. And again: We've already answered your question about using functions/conditions.

As far as I understand the problem you can do the table by a rearrangement of the outer product with some admentments
fx is a function applying product to the selcted list of elements
 fx = ( Times @@ #[[{1, 2, 3}]] + Times @@ #[[{1, 4, 5}]] + 
        Times @@ #[[{1, 2, 5, 6}]] +Times @@ #[[{1, 3, 4, 6}]] &)

The outer product generates the tensor product, its index tree can be arranged by Transpose and Join
\right|$$
 Grid[(Append[#, fx[#]] &) /@ 
       Join @@ Transpose[
        Outer[(Join[#1, #2]) &, Permutations[{0, 1, 1}], 
            Permutations[{0, 1, 2}], 1], {1, 2, 3}] , 
        Frame -> All]

in LaTeX without grid lines
$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right|$$

function
function = Block[{compose, addIndex, addLastCol, evaluateLastCol},
    addIndex = MapIndexed[{First@#2, Splice@#1} &];
    evaluateLastCol = Sign@(#1 #2 #3 + #1 #4 #5 + #1 #2 #5 #6 + #1 #3 #4 #6) &;
    addLastCol = {Splice@#, evaluateLastCol @@ #} &;
    compose = addIndex[addLastCol /@ #] &;
    {
        {"Order", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "fx"},
        Splice@compose@#
    }
] &;

code
TSet1 = Select[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], Total@# == 3 && # != {1, 1, 1} &];
TSet2 = Select[Tuples[Range[0, 1], 3], Total@# == 2 &];
Grid[function@(Catenate /@ Tuples[{TSet1, TSet2}]), Frame -> All]

display

